# json nested objects to unordered list with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parsing

What is the best why of parsing json content into an unordered list containing 
the json im getting is pretty complicated so im not sure what loops to use

the jason format im getting in my ajax function:

```
     {"query-continue":{"search":{"gsroffset":40}},
"query":{"searchinfo":{"totalhits":126915},"pages":
{
"19134739":{"pageid":19134739,"ns":6,"title":"File:Alius Stones.jpg","imagerepository":"local","imageinfo":[{"url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Alius_Stones.jpg","descriptionurl":"https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Alius_Stones.jpg"}]},
"29549993":{"pageid":29549993,"ns":6,"title":"File:Bladder stones.jpg","imagerepository":"local","imageinfo":[{"url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Bladder_stones.jpg","descriptionurl":"https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bladder_stones.jpg"}]},
"33026732":{"pageid":33026732,"ns":6,"title":"File:Bobryvnia stones.JPG","imagerepository":"local","imageinfo":[{"url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Bobryvnia_stones.JPG","descriptionurl":"https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bobryvnia_stones.JPG"}]},
"24935535":{"pageid":24935535,"ns":6,"title":"File:Volcanic stones.jpg","imagerepository":"local","imageinfo":[{"url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1d/Volcanic_stones.jpg","descriptionurl":"https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Volcanic_stones.jpg"}]}}}}
```

so there is a sub-object "pages" who have pageid objects etc who have imageinfo objects who have urls.
from those i want to grab the url only an use it to construct a simple `ul` containing`<img>` with those urls as sources for the images. 
something like

```
    <ul>
<li><img src=url(***json url data here***)></li>
<li><img src=url(***json url data here***)></li>
</ul>
```

how do i drill down to the right level in the json and what loop should i use to populate the `<ul>` with img tags with appropriate sources?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g7djgase/1/

Comment: great. no need for parsejson?

Comment: If you have an object not a string then there is no need

Comment: excuse my ignorance but what is missing int he fiddle for the `<li><img></li>'s to show up in the html (into the `<ul></ul>` i created)

Comment: Just append it to the body to see the result in fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/g7djgase/2/